# Laptop detects monitor but does not show input

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, vga

I recently bought a HDMI (male) to VGA (male) cable to connect my laptop to a second screen. When I detect screens, it detects the very screen that is connected to the cable, but it doesn't show input. I have updated my graphics cards drivers, both of them, to no avail.

My laptop specs (HP Pavilion Power 15):

- Intel i7 7700HQ
- Intel HD 630 Graphics card
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
- HDMI gate

My screen specs (Samsung S22C300 Monitor):

- VGA gate
- 1920 x 1080p

My main screen runs on the Intel HD 630 Graphics card and the additional monitor runs on the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

I hope you can help me

Edit: I bought an "active signal sender", however not a "signal adapter/ inverter"

Comment: What adapter did you buy? You would need a active one adapter (not a passive one) to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do HDMI to VGA cables actually work as advertised?](https://superuser.com/questions/1037748/do-hdmi-to-vga-cables-actually-work-as-advertised)

Comment: Related one: https://superuser.com/questions/1174736/can-a-vga-monitor-be-used-with-a-dvi-hdmi-graphics-card

Comment: @CaldeiraG You seem to be right, couldn't find those questions with my phrasing. I bought one identical to the first link you posted. Seems like I'll need an adapter for it. Thanks